# Java and XSS: How to html escape a JSON string to protect against XSS?

Tags: java, json, jackson, xss

In Java, we've got some code that takes a complex java object and serializes it to json. It then writes that json directly to the markup of a page, in a script tag, assigning it to a variable.

```
// Get object as JSON using Jackson
ObjectWriter jsonWriter = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String json = jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(complexObject);

// Write JSON out to page, and assign it to a javascript variable.
Writer out = environment.getOut();
out.write("var data = " + json);
```

The complex object can have end user content in it, which could open us up to XSS attacks.

**How can I get a json version of the complex java object that has each json attribute HTML escaped, to protect against XSS injection?**

I've read the [OWASP XSS Guide](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) and the best I've come up with so far is this, which HTML escapes the entire JSON string, then undoes the quotes, so it can be assigned to a variable in javascript. I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this seems to work. Any suggestions?

```
private String objectToHtmlEscapedJson(Object value) {
    try {
        String result = jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(value);
        result = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(result);
        result = result.replace("&quot;", "\"");
        return result;
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

Comment: Another approach could be to iterate over the object entries and individually escape each key and value - that way there is also less chance of malformed data getting passed to your JS. Since you read the OWASP guide you may want to take a look at [their anti-XSS encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder) too.

Comment: thanks! that's a great suggestion. I was considering it, but was hoping that owasp or someone else had wrapped up this task exactly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A possible approach could be to iterate over the object entries and individually escape each key and value once the node is constructed by your chosen library.

Following my comment above, I've implemented a simple recursive solution using both [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (from your question) and [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson), a different library where objects are slightly easier to construct and the code is more readable. The escaping mechanism used is the [OWASP Java Encoder](https://github.com/OWASP/owasp-java-encoder):

### Jackson

```
private static JsonNode clean(JsonNode node) {
    if(node.isValueNode()) { // Base case - we have a Number, Boolean or String
        if(JsonNodeType.STRING == node.getNodeType()) {
            // Escape all String values
            return JsonNodeFactory.instance.textNode(Encode.forHtml(node.asText()));
        } else {
            return node;
        }
    } else { // Recursive case - iterate over JSON object entries
        ObjectNode clean = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = it.next();
            // Encode the key right away and encode the value recursively
            clean.set(Encode.forHtml(entry.getKey()), clean(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return clean;
    }
}
```

### GSON

```
private static JsonElement clean(JsonElement elem) {
    if (elem.isJsonPrimitive()) { // Base case - we have a Number, Boolean or String
        JsonPrimitive primitive = elem.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if(primitive.isString()) {
            // Escape all String values
            return new JsonPrimitive(Encode.forHtml(primitive.getAsString()));
        } else {
            return primitive;
        }
    } else if (elem.isJsonArray()) { // We have an array - GSON requires handling this separately
        JsonArray cleanArray = new JsonArray();
        for(JsonElement arrayElement: elem.getAsJsonArray()) {
            cleanArray.add(clean(arrayElement));
        }
        return cleanArray;
    } else { // Recursive case - iterate over JSON object entries
        JsonObject obj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject clean = new JsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry :  obj.entrySet()) {
            // Encode the key right away and encode the value recursively
            clean.add(Encode.forHtml(entry.getKey()), clean(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return clean;
    }
}
```

Sample input (both libraries):

```
{
    "nested": {
        "<html>": "<script>(function(){alert('xss1')})();</script>"
    },
    "xss": "<script>(function(){alert('xss2')})();</script>"
}
```

Sample output (both libraries):

```
{
    "nested": {
        "&lt;html&gt;": "&lt;script&gt;(function(){alert(&#39;xss1&#39;)})();&lt;/script&gt;"
    },
    "xss": "&lt;script&gt;(function(){alert(&#39;xss2&#39;)})();&lt;/script&gt;"
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think [Paul Benn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50871867/26510) is the best approach overall, but if you don't want to iterate over the json nodes, you could consider using [Encode.forHtmlContent](https://owasp.github.io/owasp-java-encoder/encoder/apidocs/org/owasp/encoder/Encode.html#forHtmlContent-java.lang.String-), which doesn't escape quotes. I feel this is probably safe as I can't think of how introducing an additional quote into a quoted string could cause an exploit. I'll leave it to the reader to review the docs and decide for themselves!

#### ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="org.owasp.encoder" name="encoder" rev="1.2.1"/>
```

and some code to do the html encoding

```
private String objectToJson(Object value)
{
    String result;
    try
    {
        result = jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(value);
        return Encode.forHtmlContent(result);
    }
    catch (JsonProcessingException e)
    {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating [Paul Benn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8027026/paul-benn) answer of the Gson version to include json value being an array

```
private static JsonElement clean(JsonElement elem) {
    if(elem.isJsonPrimitive()) { // Base case - we have a Number, Boolean or String
        JsonPrimitive primitive = elem.getAsJsonPrimitive();
        if(primitive.isString()) {
            // Escape all String values
            return new JsonPrimitive(Encode.forHtml(primitive.getAsString()));
        } else {
            return primitive;
        }
    }  else if( elem.isJsonArray()  ) { // If the object is an array  "cars": ["toyota", "nissan", "bmw"]
        JsonArray jsonA = elem.getAsJsonArray();
        JsonArray cleanedNewArray = new JsonArray();
        for(JsonElement jsonAE: jsonA) {
            cleanedNewArray.add(clean(jsonAE));
        }
        return cleanedNewArray;
    } else { // Recursive case - iterate over JSON object entries
        JsonObject obj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonObject clean = new JsonObject();
        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry :  obj.entrySet()) {
            // Encode the key right away and encode the value recursively
            clean.add(Encode.forHtml(entry.getKey()), clean(entry.getValue()));
        }
        return clean;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to describe what is new in your update.

Answer (score 2):

Adding a version of [JKRo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9073305/jkro) using Jackson with Esapi.

```
private JsonNode clean(JsonNode node, ObjectMapper mapper) {
    if(node.isValueNode()) { // Base case - we have a Number, Boolean or String
        if(JsonNodeType.STRING == node.getNodeType()) {
            // Escape all String values
            return JsonNodeFactory.instance.textNode(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(node.asText()));
        } else {
            return node;
        }
    } else if(node.isArray()) { // If the object is an array  "cars": ["toyota", "nissan", "bmw"]
        ArrayNode cleanedNewArray = mapper.createArrayNode();
        for (final JsonNode objNode : node) {
            cleanedNewArray.add(clean(objNode, mapper));
        }
        return cleanedNewArray;
    } else { // Recursive case - iterate over JSON object entries
        ObjectNode clean = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode();

        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> it = node.fields(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = it.next();
            // Encode the key right away and encode the value recursively
            clean.set(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML(entry.getKey()), clean(entry.getValue(), mapper));
        }
        return clean;
    }
}
```

Request Body:

```
{
"param1": "<input class='btn btn-default' value='0' placeholder='Ingrese sus datos'></input>",
"param3": [
{
    "nombre" : "<input class='btn btn-default' value='0' placeholder='Ingrese sus datos'></input>",
    "apellido": "<script>alert('Hola mundex');</script>"
},
{
    "param4": {
        "nombre" : "<input class='btn btn-default' value='0' placeholder='Ingrese sus datos'></input>",
        "apellido": "<script>alert('Hola mundex');</script>"
    }
}],
"param2": "alert('Hola')"
}
```

Response Body:

```
{
"param1": "&lt;input class&#x3d;&#x27;btn btn-default&#x27; value&#x3d;&#x27;0&#x27; placeholder&#x3d;&#x27;Ingrese sus datos&#x27;&gt;&lt;&#x2f;input&gt;",
"param3": [
    {
        "nombre": "&lt;input class&#x3d;&#x27;btn btn-default&#x27; value&#x3d;&#x27;0&#x27; placeholder&#x3d;&#x27;Ingrese sus datos&#x27;&gt;&lt;&#x2f;input&gt;",
        "apellido": "&lt;script&gt;alert&#x28;&#x27;Hola mundex&#x27;&#x29;&#x3b;&lt;&#x2f;script&gt;"
    },
    {
        "param4": {
            "nombre": "&lt;input class&#x3d;&#x27;btn btn-default&#x27; value&#x3d;&#x27;0&#x27; placeholder&#x3d;&#x27;Ingrese sus datos&#x27;&gt;&lt;&#x2f;input&gt;",
            "apellido": "&lt;script&gt;alert&#x28;&#x27;Hola mundex&#x27;&#x29;&#x3b;&lt;&#x2f;script&gt;"
        }
    }
],
"param2": "alert&#x28;&#x27;Hola&#x27;&#x29;"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the contents inside the variable "data" will be used for creating HTML markup with dangerous DOM methods (as explained in the OWASP guides) then it is okay to employ the provided answers.

But maybe you need to preserve the actual values of the json data for further processing (including its dangerous characters), then the only obvious issue in your example occurs when the json includes a closing SCRIPT tag (which breaks the browser's JavaScript parsing and may allow the inclusion of an attacker provided new script.) It will NOT be detected by Jackson!

A solution using base64 encoding:

```
String json = jsonWriter.writeValueAsString(complexObject);
String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
out.write("var encodedData = '" + json + "';");
out.write("var data = JSON.parse(window.atob(encodedData));");
```

See also:
[How to get Jackson to escape a </script> in output string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288322/how-to-get-jackson-to-escape-a-script-in-output-string)