# Add javascript code to page on jquery onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, tracking

I need to add in some javascript code onto my page after an onclick. I have the following code but nothing happens on the button click and the page just outputs:

```
'); }); }); [button]
```

Here is my code:

```
<button type="submit" id="btn">button</button>

<div id="code"></div>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#btn').click(function(){
        jQuery('#code').append('<script>alert("WORKING");</script>');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work in a jsbin:
http://jsbin.com/likubo/1/edit

Comment: why not just use a boolean variable to toggle the behavior on after the button is clicked?

Comment: Why append a script that runs alert when you can just run the alert?

Comment: alert was just an example, i'm actually wanting to put javascript tracking code in but this was much cleaner as an example

Comment: That's means you need to escape in some way the closing script tag, e.g using `jQuery('#code').append('<script>alert("WORKING");</scr'+'ipt>');`. See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atmwfob5/  Other relevant thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/236106/1414562

Comment: `.append('<script>alert("WORKING");<\/script>');`

Comment: Does appending a script even do anything? If it's not there on page load it won't do anything.

Comment: would you be able to wrap that tracking code in a function and then call that function with whatever trigger you want? (so that it'll only track/do whatever when the function its wrapped in is called)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by escaping the forward slash in </script>. The closing script tag is not allowed in inline Javascript, as it messes with the way the code is parsed:

```
        jQuery('#code').append('<script>alert("WORKING");<\/script>');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a surprisingly simple task and doesnt require Jquery -- although you can execute the function with or without Jquery, however you like.

```
function AddNewExternalScriptToThisPage(ExternalScriptURLPath) {
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = ExternalScriptURLPath;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
}
```

You can also add in an onload event if you want:

```
function AddNewExternalScriptToThisPage(ExternalScriptURLPath) {
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var newScript = document.createElement('script');
    newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
    newScript.src = ExternalScriptURLPath;
    newScript.onload=scriptHasLoadedContinue;
    headID.appendChild(newScript);
}
```