# Setting ng-model to a string containing </script> clogs angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, model, escaping

I was toying around with the plunker utilized by angular's own site at the document of ng-model:

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

If one sets the $scope.val to any string containing the '< /script>' bit in it the example seizes to work:

```
       $scope.val = 'problem </script> why?'
```

The only workaround I've found was to escape / ala:

```
       $scope.val = 'no problem like this <\/script> whats going on?'
```

This doesn't seem to be happening with any other tag, say 'span', 'div' and so on. Is this 'feature' documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is simply the fact that `</script>` in the middle of your javascript code is interpreted by the browser as the closure of the script tag.

A common workaround in this case is to write it as `'<' + '/script>'` instead.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

Similar question in stackoverflow:

[Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: Good catch! Is there any other tag I need to be on the lookout for when writing code inside <script> tags in html? Any links to documentation appreciated. Thumbs up again and thank you.

Comment: I'm not really sure, sorry... I'd suggest you to give a look to javascript section of Mozilla MDN.

Comment: Thanks again. I found something indeed and will update the answer to make the link more visible to anyone that might stumble upon similar problems.