# Display javascript code with text()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to display some `javascript` within pre/code tags using `jQuery` `text()` method. Like this:

```
 jQuery(".output").wrapInner( "<pre><code></code></pre>" );
 jQuery(".output code").text("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://somedomain/?" + apiKeyValue.val() + "></script>");
```

However the script tags produce a

`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

error in the console. How can I display the script tags?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
jQuery(".output code").text("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://somedomain/?" + apiKeyValue.val() + "></script>");
```

with:

```
jQuery(".output code").text("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://somedomain/?" + apiKeyValue.val() + "></"+"script>");
```

or:

```
jQuery(".output code").text("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://somedomain/?" + apiKeyValue.val() + "><\/script>");
```

You need to break the `</script>` tag (`"</"+"script>"`) or escape the `/` (`"<\/script>"`)

As pointed out by [TreeTree](https://stackoverflow.com/users/406276/treetree) in the comment, for a detailed explanation, please read [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: I think you also need to replace `text(".....")` with `text('.....')` as `html attributes` is better to be quoted with `" "` like `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: I think an explanation of why you have to do this would go a long way. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write.