# Script injection affects jquery template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I tried to load string using {{ html }} in jquery template.
But script injection affects {{html }}.
How restrict script injection.

Comment: are you using jquery-template or jsrender

Comment: @ArunPJohny jquery-template

Comment: can you recreate the issue in http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6budswe9/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny I updated the code in http://jsfiddle.net/6budswe9/3/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write - it is not the problem of jquery-template.... it is because of how html is parsing the `script` tag

Answer (score 0):

It is not the problem is jQuery-template, it is because that is how html parses the `<script>` element within string literals. See [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

If you want to parse and execute the script, then an easy way is to move the script to a separate file(and include that file in the html page) instead of inlining it.

Or you can escape it like

```js
testTemplate = "<i>{{html txt}}</i>";
$.template('testTemplate', testTemplate);
$.tmpl("testTemplate", {
  txt: "<b>bold</b> and \x3Cscript>alert('abc')\x3C/script>"
}).appendTo("#target");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.js"></script>
<ul id="target"></ul>
```

Comment: Is any other way to restrict that scenario?

Comment: @user3312945 none that I'm aware of