# retrieve text from code-element with unescaped < and > using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display Java source code in an html site.

When I escape all > and < before pasting the code into the html, it obviously works, everything is displayed correctly.

When I don't, a HashMap is displayed like this:

```
HashMapclass="string">"">> map = new HashMap<>();
```

which should be

```
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

When I use JQuery's text() method and print the result to the console, I get this:

```
HashMap> map = new HashMap<>();
```

And when I use the html() method, I get this:

```
HashMap<string, arraylist<string="">&gt; map = new HashMap&lt;&gt;();
```

How should I retrieve the text from the code-Element so that I can correctly escape > and

Doing the same thing with XML source code works. I use

```
$(this).html()
```

to get the text in the code-Element and then escape the characters. The XML is then displayed with tags instead of just text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you insert into your html a line like:

```
<code id="okai">HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();</code>
```

You have to understand that HTML will consider the `"<String"` as the beginning of a new tag and because there is no corresponding end tag (i.e.: `</String>`) the html code is rendered in:

```
HashMap> map = new HashMap<>();
```

If you take a look with the development tool (press F12 in chrome) you will appreciate what i intend: in the code tag you have now two tags: a string and another wrong tag.

The same problem happens if you write a `</script>` tag inside a script (please refer to: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write`).

So there is no need to proceed with the text or html jquery functions because the imput html has been just changed by the html interpreter.

To insert a java source inside your html page I prefer a way like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var newTxt = $('#myCodeId').html().replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', '');
            $('#myCodeId').text(newTxt);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<code id="myCodeId"><!--HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<>();--></code>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this great answer!