# Show some part of js code inside <body> tag

Tags: javascript

I have a function in head, function is -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
            var divContents = $("#page-wrap").html();
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        });
    </script>
```

problem is part of the above function showing in the body tag and off course web page.

this is the part of js code that showing in web page

```
'); printWindow.document.close(); printWindow.print(); });
```

I have test the code in one server look like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        var divContents = $("#page-wrap").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body>');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    });
```

and another server code looking like this-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        var divContents = $("#page-wrap").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
        printWindow.document.write(divContents);
        printWindow.document.write('<script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"2aa6bb7413","applicationID":"18758918","transactionName":"MlFbYRRZWBdSWkcPWwsbbEcPF1kWV1xBSEQNRA==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":50,"atts":"HhZYF1xDSxk=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}
```

I don't understand what is the problem . Any help greatly appreciated !
thanks .

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) . Do not use `document.write()`

Comment: @Raptor, for new windows and iframes, `document.open`, `write` and `close` is just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a `</script>` in a string somewhere that you don't show us ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: I checked "</script>" nothing like this @kaiido

Comment: in which browser are you experiencing it ?

Comment: Chrome Version 50.0.2661.102 m  and mozila version 46.0.1 both

Comment: Can't repro... sorry. I can't get where it does come from either. But for a fix, try to escape `'<\/body><\/html>`.

Comment: @Kaiido this script add automatically could you please suggest me what is the problem script is <script type="text/javascript">window.NREUM||(NREUM={});NREUM.info={"beacon":"bam.nr-data.net","licenseKey":"2aa6bb7413","applicationID":"18758918","transactionName":"MlFbYRRZWBdSWkcPWwsbbEcPF1kWV1xBSEQNRA==","queueTime":0,"applicationTime":50,"atts":"HhZYF1xDSxk=","errorBeacon":"bam.nr-data.net","agent":""}