# If condition load external javascript script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following DIV:

```
<div id="top-ad"></div>
```

I want to load an external advertisement javascript script if the browser size is higher than 728. So, I need something like this:

```
<div id="top-ad">
     <script>
     if(window.innerWidth >= 728) {
        <script src="//go.*****.com/?id=****"></script>
     }
     </script>
</div>
```

Of course the above won't work. I tried to load the script asynchronously using Jquery like this:

```
<div id="top-ad">
     <script>
     if(window.innerWidth >= 728) {
        $.getScript("//go.*****.com/?id=****");
     }
     </script>
</div>
```

I tried the above method but I get the following error:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.

I don't have access to the DOM elements inside the loaded script and they are actually dynamic and I'm not allowed to alter them. Is there a way to load the script inside the `div` element based on the if condition?

Comment: Or even `if(innerWidth>=728) document.write('<script src="..."><'+'/script>');`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol It is very bad practice to append scripts like that.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer171 It is, I agree, but the script being appended itself uses `document.write` (as shown by the error message), so the only way to make that ad network's script work is to `document.write` it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the script you're loading uses `document.write()`, you have to use `document.write` to add the script in your `if` statement.

```
if (window.innerWidth >= 728) {
    document.write('<script src="//go.*****.com/?id=****"></sc' + 'ript>');
}
```

Notice that you have to split up `</script>`, otherwise it will end the `<script>` tag that runs your script. See [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: I have also another question, by splitting the closing `script` tag like this, doesn't the tag get broken?

Comment: No, because the concatenation puts it back together, so it's not broken when `document.write()` adds it to the document.

Comment: @MichaelSamuel I've added a link to a question that explains it.