# How to Debug a JavaScript code when it is loaded by document.write?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, nwjs

I can see the code in Element view in Chrome, but not in source because it is load by `document.write` function.

How do I set a breakpoint in this case?

Comment: there _has_ to be a source for it somewhere, check the network tab an dig through the .js files if needed.

Comment: Adding the `debugger` keyword  should be enough in the code you are trying to append

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have access to the source code that generates the document.write, you can add a call to the 'debugger' like this:

```
<script>
document.write('<sc' + 'ript> debugger; alert(0);</s' + 'cript>');
</script>
```

I you have the debugger opened on chrome, it will stop the execution and show the generated code on the Sources tab.

Comment: Why does it has to be '<sc' + 'ript> debugger; alert(0);</s' + 'cript>' not '<script> debugger; alert(0);</script>' ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write