# How to escape HTML special characters in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Take the code below: it obviously fails because the `</script>` tag in the string literal is not escaped.

```
<script>
var myquestion = "What is the tag used to mark the end of a Javascript section?";
var myanswer = "It's </script>!";
alert(myanswer.length);

function someMoreCode() {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

However if I do escape it as shown below, the string variable now contains the literal `It's &lt;/script>`, not `It's </script>`:

```
<script>
var myquestion = "What is the tag used to mark the end of a Javascript section?";
var myanswer = "It's &lt;/script>";
alert(myanswer.length);

function someMoreCode() {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

The popup box will show 17 instead of the expected 14 which is the length of the string `It's </script>`.

How can I define a string to have the contents `It's </script>`?

I would like a generic method that can be applied to any string as the actual string contents will be coming from user provided data stored in a database, so doing something like `"<"+"/script"` wouldn't be suitable.

Comment: Stuff it in an external .js or see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write

Comment: Use a backslash`<\/script>`

Answer (score 2):

You can escape the slash using a backslash:

```html
<script>
    var myquestion = "What is the tag used to mark the end of a Javascript section?";
    var myanswer = "It's <\/script>!";
    console.log(myanswer);
    
    function someMoreCode() {
        // ...
    }
</script>
```

(`alert` replaced with `console.log` for demonstration purposes)