# Angular.module is not loading in IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, internet-explorer

My application is trying to load the angular module discApp . This is working without any issues in Chrome . But in IE11 i am getting an error like below

> object doesn't support property or method 'module' .

Angular Version is using is v1.5.5. If i try ctrl+F5 its loading correctly . Is there any way to fix this issue?
My Js Code where the error throwing in IE is below .

```
'use strict';
var discApp = angular.module('discApp', ['discApp.controllers']); //Error in this line
```

Below is the code where i am adding the angular.js

```
<script>document.write("<script type='text/javascript' 
src='js/angular/angular.js?v=" + Date.now() + "'><\/script>");</script>
```

Comment: _"If i try ctrl+F5 its loading correctly"_  this doesn't really make sense. Under what condition does the error actually occur?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/docs/guide/ie), IE 9 through 11 is supported. Can you share more of your code? How and where are you including the `angular.js` script file?

Comment: The error occurs when i click on the link to launch the module very first time . First time i am getting the error mentioned above . After getting the error if i try ctrl+F5 module loads without any error. I modified the question with how i am including the angular.js

Comment: Why include it that way? Seems like it's just asking for issues

Comment: Earlier it was just like                                                                                    
    <script src="js/angular/angular.js"></script> But later to handle the cache i changed it with document.write and Date

Comment: And does it work when you don't use `document.write()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to modify your code as below, and check whether it meets the same error?

```
'use strict';
var discApp = angular.module('discApp', []);
```

If it still meets the same error, perhaps the issue is related to the angular.js reference, try to use the following script to load angular.js reference:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

If the error disappears, the issue is related to the 'discApp.controllers', you could check it.