# Is Vue's "v-model" vulnerable to XSS?

Tags: vue.js

I'm taking user-inputted data from the server and rendering it back into an input element on the client, which is using Vue.

If I have `<input :value="untrustedValue">`, I imagine this opens up to XSS attacks just like vanilla HTML `<input>` such as, if a user types in `"> <script>alert('XSS injection')</script>`

Is this still the case when using the `v-model` attribute, considering that Vue does a little magic behind the scenes?

Comment: _"I image this opens up to XSS attacks"_ it does not and nor does `v-model` ~ https://jsfiddle.net/tbp7hkg6/

Comment: The only thing you need to worry about is having `"<script>"` in a string (see [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)). Your server-side code should be encoding that correctly though

Comment: @Phil So, it's safe...given that an attacker writes their XSS injection with split `<script>` tags? In your demo, merging the `<script>` tags back together allows the injection to happen, making it vulnerable to attack. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you?

Comment: You asked if Vue was vulnerable to XSS via binding (including `v-model`) and the answer is no. Any `<script>` block that includes `<script>` in a string literal is vulnerable to the parsing issue mentioned in the post I linked above. Injection of user-supplied values into `<script>` sections should be treated very carefully however that's the concern of the server-side rendered and not Vue

Comment: I think your comment could have been more clear if you said, **"yes, using untrusted data with any HTML element attributes, whether using Vue or not, is vulnerable to XSS attacks. Vue does not do anything special with binding or `v-model` to avoid this."** The "why" would be the issue with `<script>` that you've described. Is any of that wrong?

Comment: The thing is, Vue does treat attribute binding specially. For example, you cannot inject `"` to break out of the current attribute value. The issue with `<script>` happens at parse time. The string value isn't even making it into the attribute

Comment: So although Vue does avoid some possible cases, untrusted user data still needs to be sanitized when using directly with attributes such as `value` or `v-model` because it doesn't avoid cases where an attacker injects `<script>`, correct?

Comment: Not just with Vue but with any JavaScript

Comment: No, because `:value` doesn't insert anything into the HTML.
But if you store an `v-model` value in some variable and insert it into HTML by `v-html`, you may have some problems with XSS