# Does end of script tag take priority than backtick?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am developing page builder widget. I have to save entire html of edited page to local storage and database. PHP script will load saved html from database, and javascript would save it to local storage, and page builder widget script will parse html saved in local storage.

The problem is that when the html includes `<script></script>` tag, it won't load successfully. For example, the following script will show error, if html includes `script` tag.

```
<script>
    <?php $html = $db->getPageHtml();?>
    window.localStorage.setItem('pb_html', `<?php echo $html?>`);
</script>
```

For example, if $html is set as `</script>` the following script will show error:

```
<script>
window.localStorage.setItem('test', `</script>`);
</script>
```

The other html tags are successfully rendered. I think `</script>` take priority than ` (backtick) when javascript is parsed by browser.

PHP function `htmlspecialchar` won't solve this problem because it converts `<` and `>` to `&lt;` and `&gt;`. And page builder javascript don't understand it. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Don’t use ` instead use ' (straight quote)

Comment: What if html has ' ?

Comment: Then you will have to use json_encode function basically wrap in it. That’s one way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers generally don't parse the script when looking for the `</script>` tag. First they extract everything between `<script>` and `</script>`, then this is parsed as JavaScript. It doesn't matter what type of quotes are used around the tag, since it isn't parsed at that point.

The usual way to avoid problems when you have a literal string containing `</script>` is to split it up.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('test', `</sc` + `ript>`);
```

See [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236073/why-split-the-script-tag-when-writing-it-with-document-write)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is `</script>` is generated by WYSIWIG editor. How can I possibly split that tag?

Comment: This is only an issue for literals in source code, data in variables is not affected.