# Trying to port a SO confguration solution for Vue.js from JS to basic TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2

In this SO post, shows how to add a simple config to a Vue app,

[Link to SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114173/vue-js-with-an-external-configuration-file)

The top answer uses the following JS code.

```
    fetch(process.env.BASE_URL + "config.json")
  .then((json) => {
    json().then((config) => {
       Vue.prototype.$config = config
       new Vue({
         router,
         store,
         render: (h) => h(App)
       }).$mount("#app")
    })
})
```

which I put in my TS code, and get the following error.

> ERROR in D:/TFS/StudentPortal4Vue/clientapp/src/main.ts(44,13): 44:13
> This expression is not callable.   Type 'Response' has no call
> signatures.
> 42 |         .then((json) =>
> 43 |         {
>
> > 44 |             json().then((config) =>
> > |             ^
> > 45 |             {
> > 46 |                 Vue.prototype.$config = config;
> > 47 |                 new Vue({ Version: typescript 4.3.2

It's obvious to me that I have a type problem, but I'm stumped as to how to fix it.

(Super new at ts, and old but noobish at JS & Vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in the code ...should look like this:

```js
fetch(process.env.BASE_URL + "config.json")
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((config) => {
       Vue.prototype.$config = config
       new Vue({
         router,
         store,
         render: (h) => h(App)
       }).$mount("#app")
})
```

Comment: That looks like it worked, how do it use it in a situation like this:

Vue.use( Auth,
    {
        issuer: this.$config.okta_issuer,
        client_id: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:8080/callback',
        scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'email' ],
        tokenManager: { storage: 'sessionStorage' },
    } );