# Trying to configure Okta from config.js in a Vue app, in typescript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, configuration

I'm trying to get our vue + okta app to work pulling the okta values from a congif.json in the public folder (so we can build and deploy automatically to various environments)

I'm following this pattern for the config.

[Vue js with an external configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60114173/vue-js-with-an-external-configuration-file)

Does Okta  have an example of using okta with a config.json in the public folder to hold the values(in typescript by preference)?

I'm doing this, but it's not working, is

in main.ts

```
      const sPath = `${process.env.BASE_URL} ${"config.json"}`;
//      fetch(process.env.BASE_URL + "config.json")
      fetch(sPath)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((config) =>
        {
            Vue.prototype.$config = config;
            new Vue({
                router,
                store,
                render: (h) => h(App)
            }).$mount("#app");
        })
```

Then in router\index.ts

```
const confObj = Vue.prototype.$config;// confObj is undefiend here - EWB

//Vue.use( Auth,
//    {
//        confObj,
       
//    } );
debugger;
Vue.use( Auth,
    {
        issuer: confObj.issuer,
        client_id: confObj.client_id,
        redirect_uri: confObj.redirect_uri,
        scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'email' ],
        tokenManager: { storage: 'sessionStorage' },
    } );


Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

When I get to it , configObj is still undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Vue.prototype.$config = require('/public/config.json')`
like so

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.prototype.$config = require('/public/config.json')
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    beforeCreate: function () {
        console.log(this.$config)
    },
}).$mount('#app')
```

in your example

```
Vue.prototype.$config = require('/public/config.json')
const confObj = Vue.prototype.$config;
Vue.use( Auth,
    {
        issuer: confObj.issuer,
        client_id: confObj.client_id,
        redirect_uri: confObj.redirect_uri,
        scopes: [ 'openid', 'profile', 'email' ],
        tokenManager: { storage: 'sessionStorage' },
    } );


Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be importing `router/index.ts` at the top of the file before the config is fetched.

You could defer that import until the fetch occurs:

```js
// import router from './router' ❌

const sPath = `${process.env.BASE_URL} ${"config.json"}`;
fetch(sPath)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((config) => {
     Vue.prototype.$config = config;

     new Vue({
       router: require('./router'),
       store,
       render: (h) => h(App)
     }).$mount("#app");
  })
```