# Contentful SSR React App Getting Error after Hydrating

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, contentful

I am making a SSR react contentful application and after I hydrate the app correctly I am getting an error related to the data I got correctly from the server. It thinks the key I am passing to the contentful API does not exist but it did for the server request. I can't quite figure out why it would throw this error this way. Has anyone run into this the code is here minus the keys for obvious reasons.

https://github.com/JoshBowdenConcepts/goop-troop-collective

the current error looks like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expected parameter accessToken
    K contentful.js:53
    267 client.js:8
    l (index):1
    100 main.27827bac.chunk.js:1
    l (index):1
    r (index):1
    t (index):1
    <anonymous> main.27827bac.chunk.js:1
contentful.js:53:10
```

Cheers,

Comment: Could you include a [minimal, reproducible example of the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Or at least the relevant errors and pieces of code? As it stands, the question is not exactly in a Q&A format which StackOverflow is best suited for. The Help center has some tips that you might be interested in: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: How would you go about that without adding private keys because as the question stands you can't make it reproducable without them and I can't provide them.

Comment: Is that the whole stack trace? Do I understand correctly, that this error occurrs on the client side?

Comment: Yes that is and maybe that in itself is the issue because the client side doens't have access to the config variables?

Comment: There is the full console log. I am wondering how I would get this info on the client correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that while the server-side rendered tree passes `siteInfo` to `<App />`, the clientside bundle's `index.js` does not. If you were running a development build of React, you'd probably see errors related to the hydrated tree differing from the DOM. You'll need to pass the initial props to the client somehow - one popular trick is to inject them into a global variable and pass that, for example:

Server:

```
getSiteInformation().then((info) => {
  const siteInfoInjector = `<script>window.__INITIAL_PROPS = ${JSON.stringify(
    info.fields
  )};</script>`;

  return res.send(
    data.replace(
      '<div id="root"></div>',
      `${siteInfoInjector}
      <div id="root">
      ${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        <App siteInfo={info.fields} />
      )}
      </div>`
    )
  );
});
```

Client's `index.js`:

```
const initialProps = window.__INITIAL_PROPS;

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App siteInfo={initialProps} />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

A word of warning though, this injects the stringified result directly into the HTML, meaning that if your `siteTitle` is `hello </script><script>alert(1)`, you've got an XSS on your hands. One way you could fix this is by base-64 encoding the initial value:

Server:

```
const siteInfoInjector = `<script>window.__INITIAL_PROPS = "${Buffer.from(
  JSON.stringify(info.fields)
).toString("base64")}";</script>`;
```

Client:

```
const initialProps = JSON.parse(atob(window.__INITIAL_PROPS));
```

Comment: An XSS is probably not that easy to pull off in a `JSON.stringify`, it will usually escape `/` slashes to break any closing tags (which is only an issue in older browsers)

Comment: @apokryfos Do you mean backwards slashes? I gave it a test and the XSS is there for sure - for example `{siteName: 'hello </script>'}` becomes `window.__INITIAL_PROPS = {"siteName":"hello </script>"}` and even though the `</script>` is inside a string in javascript, the HTML parser terminates the `<script>` body there. The problem here is that we're baking in the values directly into the HTML.

Comment: `{siteName: 'hello </script>'}` is not what `JSON.stringify` will produce though, it's not valid JSON, and the HTML parser won't terminate the script tag within a string.

Comment: @apokryfos Sorry, I meant that with the value of `info.fields` being the former, the latter is what gets inserted into `siteInfoInjector`. Unfortunately the HTML parser absolutely will terminate the script tag even if it is within JS string. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236073/996081) for example. You can also try it out on JSFiddle or even in your browser's devtools' DOM inspector - try editing some node on the page as HTML and give it a go.

Comment: Strange I thought JSON.stringify escaped slashes. It doesn't seem to do so. I thought `</script>` was JSON encoded to `<\/script>`. I must be thinking of something else

Comment: @cbr so I am going through this to test where did you put the siteInfoInjector? I haven't tried to run scripts in the start of an app like this. Would you declare it after the app component?

Comment: @JoshBowden The `siteInfoInjector` is just a helper variable over at the server's side. The data goes to a global variable, namely `window.__INITIAL_PROPS`. The server essentially injects a `<script>` into the body of the generated HTML, which runs before your bundle's `<script>` - that way your client's source can read the value from `window.__INITIAL_PROPS`. The file I refer to as "Client's `index.js`" is `src/index.js`.

Comment: @cbr ok that makes sense and I have that setup correctly. I am still running into an error getting the accessToken. I am not sure why this is still persisting

Comment: @JoshBowden Have you updated the Github repository with the latest code?

Comment: @cbr just pushed the changes

Comment: @JoshBowden Did you remember to rebuild your client and restart the server afterwards? Have you tried changing `serviceWorker.register()` to `serviceWorker.unregister()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222980/discussion-between-cbr-and-josh-bowden).