# PHP DOMDocument cuts part of script

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom, domdocument

I try to parse such string with DOMDocument:

```
$html1 = "<script>document.write('<scr'+'ipt>alert(123);</scr'+'ipt>')</script>";
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->loadHTML($html1);
$html2 = $dom->saveHTML();
```

but `$html2` has the string

```
<html><head><script>document.write('\<scr'+'ipt\>alert(123);')</script></head></html>
```

which is missing the `</scr'+'ipt>` part.

I expect to receive the same string between script tags as in the input.

Comment: When I try this I get a warning from `loadHTML()`: **PHP Warning:  DOMDocument::loadHTML(): End tag : expected '>' in Entity, line: 1 in php shell code on line 1**

Comment: Do you have any questions about this code?

Comment: I think `DOMDocument` doesn't know that the contents of `<script>` tags should not be parsed for HTML tags. It sees `<scr` and expects it to be `<scr>`, and it sees `</scr` as an unexpected end tag.

Comment: This [PHP bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71452) is probably the most relevant, however they say it is a libxml problem. Their guidance is to escape the closing tag such as `<\/scr'+'ipt>`

Comment: For many years it was common practice to wrap JavaScript code embedded into HTML in an HTML comment (`<!-- .... // -->`) for backward compatibility with HTML parsers not aware of JavaScript. Then we collectively decided this was pointless because everybody should just upgrade their browser. Not a helpful comment, just a rant.

Comment: Topical: [Why split the <script> tag when writing it with document.write()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/236073/2943403)

Comment: What are you actually intending to do while parsing the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

If you try to load partial HTML on `DOMDocument` it gets confused as it doesn't know how to parse it and sometimes it ends up parsing it as XML.

To avoid this always be sure that the minimum of a HTML5 document is present before adding loading the document.

Also anything inside the `<script>` tags cannot have any `</` those needs to be escaped before being loaded.

In you case, satisfying the minimum requirements, it should be something like this:

```php
$html1 = "<script>document.write('<scr'+'ipt>alert(123);</scr'+'ipt>')</script>";
$html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>'. $html1 . '</head><body></body></html>';
//escape the </ sequences as <\/ inside javascripts
if(preg_match_all('/(<script.*?>)(.*?)(<\/script>)/is', $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)){
  $t = '';
  $o = 0;
  foreach($matches as $m){
    $t .= substr($html, $o, $m[0][1] - $o);
    $t .= $m[1][0].preg_replace('|<\/|', '<\/', $m[2][0]).$m[3][0];
    $o = $m[3][1] + strlen($m[3][0]);
  }
  $t .= substr($html, $o);
  $html = $t;
}


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$html2 = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $html2;
```

I just hope that this is not real code. Inserting scripts with scripts and helping you coding some code hacking injection.

Comment: Can't much of this mess be prettied up by just using `preg_replace_callback()`?  But then, if you escape the closing tag's forward slash, then won't that prevent the original functionality of the HTML?

Comment: In this short case you are right, the callback will avoid tracking and stitching the parts. I just simplified an existing code that also checks and correct what I manually did on line 2. Also, this only escape the “look like” closing tags inside the script tags. This process has been tested on production. The only case it fails when it literally has another closing script inside the script tag, but it can be bypass like the OP did.